# Parsing a Nested Array of Objects from JSON to Go

Tags: json, parsing, go, struct

I've looked through many examples of how to parse JSON using go and I understand the basics. But I cannot get an array of objects to parse properly. I have created a struct for the object but no dice!

Here's a playground about it:
<kbd>[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/UmxaqOO6nZQ)</kbd>

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Outer struct {
    Number  int      `json: "number"`
    Message string   `json: "message"`
    Person  []Person `json: "person"`
}

type Person struct {
    craft string `json: "craft"`
    name  string `json: "name"`
    }

func main() {
    text := `{"people": [{"craft": "ISS", "name": "Sergey Rizhikov"}, {"craft": "ISS", "name": "Andrey Borisenko"}, {"craft": "ISS", "name": "Shane Kimbrough"}, {"craft": "ISS", "name": "Oleg Novitskiy"}, {"craft": "ISS", "name": "Thomas Pesquet"}, {"craft": "ISS", "name": "Peggy Whitson"}], "message": "success", "number": 6}`

    textBytes := []byte(text)


    people1 := Outer{}

    err := json.Unmarshal(textBytes, &people1)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(people1)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have several mistakes in your code:

1. You have `people` field in the json but `person` in the struct declaration.
2. In the `Person` struct fields must start with upper letter.
3. Remove whitespace in the json tag `json:"name"` valid while `json: "name"` is invalid.

Here is the fixed [version.](https://play.golang.org/p/BYXpWyMEHTD)

Answer (score 0):

Updated code with issues fix:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Outer struct {
    Number  int      `json:"number"`
    Message string   `json:"message"`
    Person  []Person `json:"person"`
}

type Person struct {
    Craft string `json:"craft"`
    Name  string `json:"name"`
}

func main() {
    text := `{"person": [{"craft": "ISS", "name": "Sergey Rizhikov"}, {"craft": "ISS", "name": "Andrey Borisenko"}, {"craft": "ISS", "name": "Shane Kimbrough"}, {"craft": "ISS", "name": "Oleg Novitskiy"}, {"craft": "ISS", "name": "Thomas Pesquet"}, {"craft": "ISS", "name": "Peggy Whitson"}], "message": "success", "number": 6}`

    textBytes := []byte(text)

    people1 := Outer{}

    err := json.Unmarshal(textBytes, &people1)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    b, err := json.Marshal(people1)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("marshalling error")
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("Data : ", string(b))
}
```

Output:

```
Data :  {"number":6,"message":"success","person":[{"craft":"ISS","name":"Sergey Rizhikov"},{"craft":"ISS","name":"Andrey Borisenko"},{"craft":"ISS","name":"Shane Kimbrough"},{"craft":"ISS","name":"Oleg Novitskiy"},{"craft":"ISS","name":"Thomas Pesquet"},{"craft":"ISS","name":"Peggy Whitson"}]}
```

Check in playground: https://play.golang.org/p/tdNpgUAOLVF

Answer (score -1):

Update Person Struct Field To Public,Like This:

```golang
type AutoGenerated struct {
    People []People `json:"people"`
    Message string `json:"message"`
    Number int `json:"number"`
}
type People struct {
    Craft string `json:"craft"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}
```

use the tool and auto help your.
[Best JSON To Golang Converter](https://tools.piapia123.com/json/json-to-go)